# How to use keyboard event as part of a conditional statement

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I'm trying to make a program that outputs a key press event as a response to another keyboard event.  How do I get it to use the particular value of the key pressed in a conditional statement?  The codes I try seem to be skipping the conditional statement altogether.

Initially tried `[if key == '1':],` then tired by `[if key == 1:]`.  Also tried various means of assigning [key] to a variable.  Also tried [print('2')] instead of using `[pyautogui.typewrite('2')]`.  Tried putting the code both in on_press(key) and in on_release(key).

`

```
    import pyautogui
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

    def on_press(key):
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

    def on_release(key):
        print('{0} release'.format(key))
        k = format(key)
        if k == '1':       #THIS IS THE PART I CAN'T GET TO WORK
            pyautogui.typewrite('2', 0.5)
        if key == Key.esc:
    # Stop listener
            return False
    # Collect events until released
    with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

`

Expected to output '2' whenever I press '1' on the keyboard(in addition to the output of the keypress and keyrelease event).  The output for the pressing of '1' doesn't work.

Comment: May I suggest the pygame module?

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboard` library, in order to handle/create key events.

```
while True:  
    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):   
            print('{} is pressed'.format(1))
            break
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

the above code runs until `1` is received as a keypress. Upon pressing the key, `1 is pressed` will be printed.

You can further use other functions of this library, in order to detect a key down even too.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'll try that out first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter that your `on_press`/`on_release` receives is not the character string but rather a Key/KeyChar object, that's why you can't compare it directly with a string.

To access the keyboard input character, use `key.char` instead:

```
def on_press(key): 
    print("pressed '{}'".format(key.char))
```

Look at the example codes on pynput's documentation on how to [capture non letter keys](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.KeyCode).